# Angular 4 Select2 Ng2-Select2 - Hide only certain input search?

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

In my app, I have a many select2 dropdown, and in many forms I use many selects in the same form. Unfortunately `ng2-select2` doesn't have a placeholder `@Input` where each select could have it's own placeholder. Long story short, I created a `Pipe` where I store my `options` object and then just pass it around. Now the issue I face is that not all selects have the same data lengths. Some have 2 attributes others 3, 4, 5 and others 30, you get the idea. I'd like to be able to use the `minimumResultsForSearch` for the name is intended for, except that it's only worked with `Infinity` or '-1` so far. Is there a way to check for how many 'items' i have in my 'select' and hide if it's less than 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried everything I could to make the `minimumResultsForSearch` to work with a number other than `Infinity` or `-1` and it didn't. I ended up adding a parameter called `data` in my `Pipe` and having a conditional where I check whether or not its length is `<= 5` if so, I add a custom css class through their handy `dropdownCssClass` to hide the search input. In the in html, I get the data in the same way that the `[data]=''` property get's it.